# Executing multiple insert queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I am about to insert 365 insert records, I want to know which would be better.

1) Inserting 1000 insert queries one by one (for every record)

2) Insert like

```
insert into table name ('field1', 'field2') values (value,value),(value,value),(value,value),(value,value)
```

I want to does the second one perform faster and will it be useful.

Comment: Measure. Measure. Measure.

Comment: This is actually a good question. My first instinct would be to write a script that generates 365 individual `insert` statements, but it might actually be faster to just generate one statement. I can't answer this, but can you please test it out and let us know the results?

Comment: A good question? Surely you have better things to do?

Comment: @MitchWheat in this case, measures are unnecessary since a clear answer is in the corresponding MySQL manual page.

Comment: Thanks friends! I have been restructuring an existing code which has been producing "Database connection failed" because of this prob. The question I asked here is the very basis for the restructuring, that's Y I am not able to measure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to MySQL [INSERT plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html) we have following issues with time to spend on:

```
- Connecting
- Sending query to server
- Parsing query 
- Inserting row (1 × size of row)
- Inserting indexes: (1 × number of indexes)
- Closing
```

Due to this, multiple insert is much more faster since it will produce `Connecting`, `Sending query to server`, `Parsing query`, `Closing` overheads only once. And this is shown in manual too:

> - If you are inserting many rows from the same client at the same time, use [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html)  statements with multiple VALUES lists to insert
>     several rows at a time. This is  considerably faster (many times
>     faster in some cases) than using separate single-row  [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html)
>     statements. If you are adding data to a nonempty table, you can tune
>     the  [bulk_insert_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_bulk_insert_buffer_size) variable to make data insertion even
>     faster. See [Section 5.1.4, “Server System Variables”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html).

Answer (score 0):

Creating a batch and inserting data will be better as the database will not be hit for every INSERT statement(if each record is individually inserted).